# camel : stackoverflow error when route is called recursively

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I have a camel route which calls itself until a certain condition is met. Basically the idea is to implement the retry of route. When the application is deployed I am getting stackoverflow error when retries happen for a long period.

```
    [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - Multicast] ERROR com.application.RouteName.lambda$configure$0 - Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-batchrater-310822922-1-383133832-34058-1530798326741-0-6]
    org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-batchrater-310822922-1-383133832-34058-1530798326741-0-6]
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1779)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:351)

  .
  .
  .
  .
        Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.transformedBeanName(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1117)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:239)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.ApplicationContextRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(ApplicationContextRegistry.java:47)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:63)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInfo.createParameterMappingStrategy(BeanInfo.java:177)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInfo.<init>(BeanInfo.java:99)
```

I believe the stackoverflow error is due to the recursive call of route and I changed the route structure and now redelivery is handled by the retryDelivery mechanisms available in camel `onException()` . And my number of retries can be infinite until the condition is met.

I need to know will there be any chance of `stackOverFlow` again with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is the right approach to handle error handling redeliveries with the onException and other error handling features. Using the loop EIP leads to longer stack-frames and should not be used for looping very long. So you did the right fix.